# How to read external xml in spring boot 2.1.7 using external path as command line argument or config folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Am working on a spring boot application having external configuration.Jar file run via command prompt using following command.

```
java -jar Service-1.0.jar --spring.config.additional-location=C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Springboot/
```

Need to pass external configuration path via command line argument,because they may varying.

Main class

```
@ImportResource(locations = {
        "config/spring/service-config.xml",
        "config/spring/datasource-config.xml"

})
public class ServiceMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServiceMain.class)
                .build()
                .run(args);
        for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {

        }

    }
}
```

when i run this jar it showing the following error

[image]

**EDIT 1**
changed running command

```
java -jar Service-1.0.jar --spring.config.additional-location=C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Springboot/,--external.config=C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Springboot/
```

changed main class

```
 @ImportResource(locations = {
            "${external.config}/config/spring/service-config.xml",
            "${external.config}/config/spring/datasource-config.xml"

    })
    public class ServiceMain {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServiceMain.class)
                    .build()
                    .run(args);
            for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {

            }

        }
    }
```

it showing exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'external.config' in value "${external.config}/config/spring/service-config.xml"
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at com.ge.hcit.xer.app.services.api.XERServiceMain.main(XERServiceMain.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'external.config' in value "${external.config}/config/spring/service-config.xml"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractEnvironment.java:575)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

how the importresource taking the external configuration

**EDIT 2**

Am placing configuration in config folder.external application.properties are loading in current project,but its not loading in dependency project.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationFactory
{

    public static final String REQ_CONF = "config/Configuration.xml";
    public static final String FILTER_XML_CONF = "config/DocFilter.xml";
}
```

Is the spring load external application.properties/yml files only?

Comment: `@ImportResource` takes exact locations. The `--spring.config.additional-location` is for the `application.properties` and `application.yaml` files.

Comment: is there any way to load xml configuration without hard coded the path?. external path may vary

Comment: You can add a prefix to it and provide it at runtime `${external.config}/config/spring/service-config.xml`. Then provide `--external.config` when starting the program. However generally it isn't a good idea to provide bean configuration xml files from an external location. People will do things in those they shouldn't be doing. Rather you should provide some properties which they can use o override/configure their application.

Comment: thtat means:-> java -jar Service-1.0.jar --spring.config.additional-location=C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Springboot/,--external.config =c:/<path> am i correct?

Comment: we need to place this configuration as external.its project specific @M.Deinum

Comment: I only wanted to point out that doing those things external is dangerous, as people can override add more beans then you expected. As stated you generally only want properties (urls, passwords etc.) to be externalized NOT the whole configuration of your application (which is what you now have externalized). If someone messes that configuration up it could severely impact your application and it is then on you to fix it (even the problem wasn't caused by your code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your approach.

```
Instead of command line, add that as variable in application.properties file
```

please separate place holder and remaining path,

```
like ("${external.config}"+"/spring/service-config.xml")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `file:` prefix for system resource file:

```
@ImportResource(locations = {
     "file:${external.config.location}/config/spring/service-config.xml",
     "file:${external.config.location}/config/spring/datasource-config.xml"
})
```

Run with `--external.config.location=xxx`:

```
java -jar Service-1.0.jar --external.config.location=C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Springboot
```